# Message Will Not Send To Channel w/ Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, bots

I am programming a discord bot that will send an embed to a separate channel when someone uses a command to prevent abuse and so our admins can keep an eye on usage.

I have this code:

```
@client.command()
@has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(ctx, amount=5):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount + 1) # Plus one is so that it also deletes the players purge message
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Purged Channel", description="", colour=0xe74c3c, timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
    embed.set_author(name="CS Moderation", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/938857720268865546/938863881726615602/ca6.png")
    embed.add_field(name="Staff Member", value=ctx.author.mention, inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text="Made by HeadOfTheBacons#6666", icon_url=None)
    channel = client.get_channel("938898514656784404") #Change ID of logging channel if needed
    await channel.send(embed = embed)
```

When I run this, I cannot get the embed to be sent to a different channel. I have tried checking other posts already but I have not had much luck at all. I have no errors when I use the command or try to run the bot. The point here is when someone uses the command to make a new embed, set up the preferences, specify the specific channel ID where I want this embed to be sent to, and have the computer send it off to that channel. However, it is not sending. Why is my code not working? What do I need to change in my code to make this send a message?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236, and note the edits I have made to your question - this is *not a discussion forum*, so we do not want conversational language. We *do* want a specific, focused question. I have tried to put in in a question, but this one is not focused enough. Please edit it again and make sure it is clear: exactly how do you try to use the code in order to send the embed to a different channel? When you try that, what *does* happen, and how is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: And most importantly: what kind of help is actually needed? And what steps have you taken so far in order to [diagnose](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [understand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) the problem?

Comment: so add this in ur code and then reply me with what it displayed 
```@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
  print(f"{ctx.command} - {ctx.guild} - {ctx.author} - {error}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have an **on_command_error** function in your program, it could be the reason of your no error problem.

Also not that the embed.footer can't be None, and the client.get_channel requires an Integer.

So you can try out the following code, it should work:

```
from datetime import datetime
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="prefix")


@client.command()
@has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(ctx, amount=5):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount + 1)  # Plus one is so that it also deletes the players purge message
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Purged Channel", description="", colour=0xe74c3c, timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
    embed.set_author(name="CS Moderation", icon_url=client.user.avatar_url)
    embed.add_field(name="Staff Member", value=ctx.author.mention, inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text="Made by HeadOfTheBacons#6666")
    channel = client.get_channel(938898514656784404)  # Change ID of logging channel if needed
    await channel.send(embed=embed)


client.run("TOKEN")
```